# Pass to ajax a string with "/"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a question. How would I be able to submit a string including "/".

For example:

```
$link = "string/users";

$.ajax({
    url: '/users/add_to_footer/'+$link,
    success: function(data){
});
```

In my controller, I have:

```
public function getString($string = NULL)
{

}
```

I need to be able to save the entire word "string/users". But currently, it is only saving the word before "/" meaning, it is saving only the word "string" and not "string/users".

Thanks for the help

Comment: urlencode the string by using escape(string)

Comment: Have you tried $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ?

Comment: Well, it's obvious that your framework (whatever it is) is designed to use `/` as separator. In plain PHP you can parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to your liking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try encoding it?

```
$link = "string/users";
$.ajax({
    url: '/users/add_to_footer/'+ encodeURIComponent($link),
    success: function(data){
});
```